# aws mediaconvert is suitable for social media?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-convert, aws-mediaservices

I am building a social media platform which allows the user to upload video as they want, I had try AWS MediaConvert but the price seems to be my concern, I would like to get advice on if I am right to choose AWS MediaConvert.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's a bit of late response to your question. MediaConvert is quite good interms of UGC use-cases. If your concern is only about pricing, depending on the volume, you can consider using RTS(Reserve Transcoding Slots).

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/reserved-pricing-in-aws-elemental-mediaconvert-part-1-intro-and-how-to-use-it/